# Filename does not show name of the uploaded file

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2

I have a simple form to upload file, it shows the file name with tmp extension but does not show the actual name of the uploaded file.

JSP

```
    <s:form id="uploadCSV" method="POST" action="add"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <s:file name="csv" label="Upload File"/>
        <s:submit/>
    </s:form>
```

Java

```
    private File csv;
    private String contentType;
    private String fileName;
    private String filename;
    private String FileName;
    private String Filename;

    .....   all getter setters here .....

    System.out.println("file:" + fileName);      <<null
    System.out.println("Name >>>>" + this.csv.getName()); << upload_344f45f4f54f5f5_54r5r4000.tmp
    System.out.println("Name >>>>" + this.contentType);   << null  
    System.out.println("Name >>>>" + this.FileName);     << null
    System.out.println("Name >>>>" + this.Filename);     << null
    System.out.println("Name >>>>" + this.filename);     << null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following required member fields to your Action.

```
private String csvFileName;
private String csvContentType;
```

I think you can easily figure out the naming scheme now.

```
private File <fileInputFormName>;

private String <fileInputFormName>FileName;
private String <fileInputFormName>ContentType;
```

Comment: Maybe `fileInputFromForm` is better than `formName`. :)

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes, that's much more appropriate. Updated. Thanks.